# How to turn a 2D array into a 3D diagonal matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, diagonal

Having a 2D numpy array with shape (i,j), where each column is a vector with i entries, how can I obtain a 3D numpy array with shape (j, i, i) where each j corresponds to a diagonal matrix with each vector on its diagonal without using for loops?

For example, having the 2D array `[[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[4,8]]`, I wanted to obtain a 3D array where for j=0, the matrix would be

```
[[1,0,0,0],[0,2,0,0],[0,0,3,0],[0,0,0,4]]
```

and for j=1 the matrix would be

```
[[5,0,0,0],[0,6,0,0],[0,0,7,0],[0,0,0,8]].
```

I tried `np.diag` but apparently it outputs the matrix diagonal when a 2D matrix is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->jik', a, np.eye(a.shape[0], dtype=a.dtype))
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 4]],

       [[5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 6, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 7, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 8]]])
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked as intended! However I have another question, I am not sure if I should post it here or create another topic:
-For bigger matrices, and inputting a 2D array with floats on the entries, Python becomes unable to allocate so much memory due to creating a  j*i*i matrix of floats, despite most of the elements being 0. Is there some workaround for that, in the sense of not making Python allocate so much memory to store the off-diagonal 0's?

Comment: [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html), you would need to use `dot` instead of `einsum`.